# How to use jsMath in your emails?

Tags: email, formatting

Is it possible to use jsMath to write emails? If so can anyone tell how can I do that? I need to write to my Prof. An email that needs mathematical expressions. Any clue?

**Update:**

Here is the solution I used:
https://mathoverflow.net/questions/22141/how-do-i-see-latex-math-on-any-web-page-and-in-email

Answer (score 1):

Embedding javascript on e-mails would be a huge security risk, so you can't really.

The best you can do is generate and image and link to it.

There are many services online that can let you do this.  A quick google search found **[this generator](http://propersubset.com/2010/04/tex-formula-image-generator.html)**.  Enter your TeX and press "convert", and it'll give the url of the image to link to.

Perhaps http://webapps.stackexchange.com can help you find more generators, if the one linked does not suit your purposes.

Comment: Beat me to it, and your answer is more comprehensive than mine. :)

Comment: this link will appear simply as a link, not a real math expression,  in my email, I presume?

Comment: @TheMadman: You could embed it as an image in your email and it would appear as such. Think of it as a "screenshot" of your mathematical expression.

Comment: Thanks, do you think GmailTex a risk?? Using, image urls seems a tiresome approach.

Comment: @TheMadman - GmailTex is not as huge a risk as allowing anyone to send any javascript, but it seems that your recipient must also have it installed.